# Pronoun ellipses in given context

Tags: pronouns, ellipsis

1. Give me a movie everyone loves but you just can't stand.
2. Give me a movie everyone loves but you just can't stand watching.
3. Give me a movie everyone loves but you just can't stand it.

Is the first sentence grammatically incorrect?

Comment: Initially I made a comment stating the same thing I am going to write now, but then deleted it. It was my instant guess. But as I am thinking more and more about it, it seems like I was not incorrect. Your first sentence is correct but I am doubtful of your last sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following sentence:

> John is [**old** *but* **string**].

Here *but* is a coordinator. The coordination here is [**old** *but* **string**]. The coordinator joins two elements *old* and *strong*, called coordinates. Notice here that both *old* and *strong* are under same category. Both are adjectives. There is however no reason to think that a coordinator joins just two elements of same category. What they join together is the elements of same function:

> The investigation team found out [**his location** *and* **where he came from**].

Here the elements that are joined together by the coordinator *but* is not of same category. *his location* is a Noun Phrase but *where he came from* is a subordinate interrogative clause. But these two elements have the same function in the sentence - internal complement of the verb.

> The investigation team found out *his location*. 
> The investigation team found out *where he came from*.

Now again consider the following sentence:

> Al suggested a girl [**he likes** *but* **not enough to marry**].

Here it is called Gapped Coordination. Here the two elements are **he likes** and **not enough to marry**. The gap exists in the second element. *he doesn't like [the girl] enough to marry*.

[Here *the girl* is obligatorily dropped to make the sentence grammatical, it is anaphorically linked to an antecedent. It is a Relative construction.]

In view of the above discussion, let's take a look at the sentences OP wrote:

> **1.** Give me a movie [**everyone loves** *but* **you just can't stand**]. **[CORRECT]** 
> **2.** Give me a movie [**everyone loves** *but* **you just can't stand watching**]. **[CORRECT]** 
> **3.** Give me a movie [**everyone loves** *but* **you just can't stand it**]. **[INCORRECT]**

In sentence #1 the two elements are **everyone loves** and **you just can't stand**. In both elements *movie* is omitted, and should be omitted because it is anaphorically linked to the antecedent.

Sentence #2 is similar. In sentence #2 the two elements are **everyone loves** and **you just can't stand watching**. In both elements *movie* is omitted, and should be omitted because it is anaphorically linked to the antecedent.

But your sentence #3 is incorrect because in the last element *it* is present which refers to *movie* that is anaphorically linked to the antecedent.

Answer (score 0):

As I keep repeating it not just about the grammar. Does the sentence make any sense? is it ambiguous? Context?

> *Give me a movie everyone loves but you just can't stand.*

Yes it is grammatically correct but it is not a good sentence as it stands.

I do not understand the relation ship between me- but -you?.

> Give me a movie everyone loves but I just can't stand.

> It's a movie everyone loves but you just can't stand it.

> Give me a movie everyone loves and you just can't stand.